# FastAPI: use HTTP 1.0 server

Tags: python, http, fastapi

I have a simple HTTP API server

```py
from typing import Dict

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/data/{uid}")
def data_post(uid: str, data: Dict):
    print(f"recieved data for {uid}: {data}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Currently I am running it with `uvicorn` but this is not a requirement (other ASGI servers could work as well)

My problem is that the clients that call this API use HTTP 1.0 but the server responds with HTTP 1.1

```sh
curl -v --http1.0 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"a": 123, "b":"test"}' localhost:8000/data/123abc
```

```sh
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /data/123abc HTTP/1.0
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 22
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 13:43:12 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 4
< content-type: application/json
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

I would like to know if there is a way to configure uvicorn to use HTTP 1.0 or if there is another ASGI server that can be used with FastAPI applications that can achieve this.

Unfortunatelly I can not change the clients (they are a third party product) and currently they do not support HTTP 1.1.

Comment: uvicorn only support http 1.1 and websocket

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html 

this doc said that the classic gunicorn sync worker work with nginx upstream in http 1.0
you can try to deploy your app with gunicorn sync worker and not the classic fastapi worker as shown here: https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#deployment.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html
to see a nginx config that should be compatible.

I have never try such thing but i don't see any solution with uvicorn/gunicorn or hypercorn

Comment: Running with `gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app` still results in HTTP 1.1 responses. Running with the sync worker instead results in errors since gunicorn uses WSGI whereas FastAPI uses ASGI... Good ideas but unfortunately did not work